# Animation Looping to Frame 1 Pose before Playback Completes

Tags: animation

For this example, let's say I have my Frame Range set from 1 to 20. On Frame 1 I have a character with their hand in the air, and on Frame 10 they've brought their hand down to the side.
On Frame 11, this character's hand will instantly snap up in the air identical to Frame 1.

If I have a simple 16 Frame animation, and a Playback of 2305, it will continuously loop the Poses without any actual Keyframes after Frame 16.
It only does this on one character in my scene, and on both animations that character has. Neither animation is an intentional "looping" animation.

I've tried exiting and restarting Blender.
I've double-and-triple checked ALL bone layers and scoured the Action Editor for any clues.
I don't use/haven't touched the NLA editor.

Also, for a variety of reasons, I am not at liberty to share the Blend file.

Answer (score 0):

I had somehow added a Cyclic (F-Modifier) to both animations.
For the life of me, I can't begin to fathom how that happened.

If anyone ever runs into this issue:
Open Action Editor (and affected animations)
Select all Bones and Keys
Shift+E > Clear Cyclic (F-Modifier)
Profit